# Netbeans dual screen

Tags: netbeans, screen

i've looked the web, but all i could find were bugs regarding dual screen, and not how to set it up. I cant seem to find anywere in the options dialougue on how to do it?

Comment: what version of netbeans do you have?

Comment: j/w I have 7.0 and no problems. Could you explain in detail a bit more what you want? Like have netbeans load the same way it was closed?

Comment: Im extending my screen and i want to be able to have to files open at the same time. One on each screen (and ofc. the file browser on the main screen)

Comment: I still have no issues when using netbeans 6.9.1. My guess is it is OS/graphic related

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Grab a document tab (or in fact any IDE window) and drag it to another screen. That's what works for me.

Comment: I know more people who had a problem figuring out this one. Don't worry ;)

Comment: I swapped the left/right displays in Windows Graphics Properties and physically swapped the monitor locations to fix mine. Very similar to your fix.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to configure it to use a single document interface.

This is done through the System Settings tab(I am not sure if the options are in the same location in the newer versions of netbeans.

EDIT: I just checked the below location and it does not exist in version 6.9.1

```
Tools >> Options >> Advanced Options >> IDE Configuration >> System >> System Settings
```

Your OS could also be the cause of this, and the graphic vendor of that machine(nvidia etc)

If that is the case then you will have to change your settings there not in netbeans.

Answer (score 0):

It might be late...but I think it may help to others...

Just right click on output window and select 'float group' option then you can easily drag that window to your second screen.

Float group option is dedicated for only that piece of module, so when you double click on any files in project it will not open in output window of second screen then, but in your first screen(which may happen if you just drag and drop your output window to your second screen).

Hope it helps...